# How to Achive setListFooter(View) in PreferenceFragment??

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

Their is already built in **function setListFooter(View) in PreferenceActivity** to set bottom view of Shared-preference Setting.

I was wondering **is their any available method in PreferenceFragment to achieve slimier one easily** 
Currently I am doing this with custom method.

Answer (score 0):

u can easily set bottom view in activity and make the Preferencefragment above the view. that is why fragment are so much better